# Pointer used in SDL_CreateWindow function

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Why is this syntax valid when using a pointer of type SDL_Window and then setting the pointer equal to the SDL_CreateWindow function?

```
SDL_Window * window = NULL;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOSUNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

I understand how basic pointers work and that a pointer holds a memory address and can be referenced for example:

```
int a = 7;
int* ptr = &a;
*ptr = 10;
```

this would change the value of a from 7 to 10.

Since a pointer must hold a memory address I'm confused why the following then works in SDL:

```
SDL_Window * window = NULL;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOSUNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

in particular, why can window = SDL_CreateWindow(.) that isn't a memory address is it?

Another thought I had is, perhaps it is to do with SDL being written in C, but I don't think that is the reason.

Comment: _"that isn't a memory address is it?"_ Why do you think that `SDL_CreateWindow()` won't return a valid memory address?? It's completely unclear what concrete problem you're asking about here. The function call of `SDL_CreateWindow()` is supposed to return a pointer variable.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `*ptr = 10;` and `window = SDL_CreateWindow(...);`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise that the function was supposed to return a pointer. But now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow
you will see the "syntax" of the function (ie. it's declaration):

```
SDL_Window * SDL_CreateWindow(const char *title,
                              int x, int y, int w,
                              int h, Uint32 flags)
```

The very first thing before the functions name is the return type,
which is, in fact, a *pointer to an SDL_Window object.

The reason you were confused is because numerous pages and sources state that SDL_CreateWindow "returns an SDL_Window", which is really not true at all. In fact *right under* that above declaration, on that same page, it says SDL_CreateWindow:

> "returns the window that was created"

... obviously misleading (especially to us noobs). Anyway, it returns a (pointer) variable which contains the location of an SDL_Window, as you were (somewhat rudely) told in a comment, and now already know.

Cheers, and glad I could learn this along with you.